# Howto burn an Audio-CD DIRECTLY from mp3?

Tags: sound, cd, convert, burner

I'm really pissed about the tons of optional burning-tools on my linux mint now. I can't find even one that is capable to convert and burn standard mp3s. Why is that? Why do I obviously have to install a converter to make wave-files from my mp3s to put those files on a cd? What does one need burning-tools with tons of settings, functions and nevergonnausethis, if it cant even provide me with such an easy feature? Makes me feel like using a Windows95 15 yrs ago, when cd-burning was something new.

Comment: k3b works with MP3 directly provided the relevant codecs are installed (if it plays MP3 then the codecs are there. Now, Mint is off topic here and unsubstantiated rants are unwelcome even if on topic. (And who cares about CDs in 2017 anyway?)

Comment: VLC is essential to audio performance. It does almost everything. No need to convert file types.  See this: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-burn-an-audio-cd-with-vlc

Answer (score 3):

The default music player, *Rhythmbox* in Ubuntu, supports burning an audio CD, from anything in your music library which it can normally play.